# How do i post large data from S3 bucket to an API

Tags: api, rest, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cloud

So, I have a 'csv' file around 3.5 Gb in my s3 bucket and i am supposed to post it on a REST API using AWS Lambda. But the max size the lambda can hold is 500 MB. So really confused with what I should be doing. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Have the REST API redirect to the S3 file.

Comment: So, we are using a custom API using TruVue and posting data using python scripts in the lambda function. But the file size is huge, the files less than 500Mb are easily posted on the API, but larger than 500 MB cannot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very large file to send as a REST API payload.

If you are trying to process this file with Lambda then there are other ways to do it.

Firstly the file size allocated to Lambda can be increased to 10GB. The file could be downloaded from S3 and processed.